# Proof of directional derivative explanation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

From Stewart's Calculus the part of the proof states that:
If we define a function g of the single variable h by
$$g(h) = f(x_0+ha,y_0+ha)$$
then by the definition of the derivative
$$\lim_{{h \to 0}}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$$
we have
$$g'(0) = \lim_{{ h \to 0}}\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}$$
but then author replaces $$g(h)$$ by $$f(x_0+ha,y_0+ha)$$ so we receive $$\lim_{{ h \to 0}}\frac{f(x_0+ha,y_0+ha)-f(x_0,y_0)}{h}$$
So the question is why 'h' in derivative of g(h) both in numerator and denominator equals to 'h' in $$f(x_0+ha,y_0+ha)$$
When 'h' in g(h) represents projection vector length, but 'h' in derivative of g(h) represents small changes in input?

Comment: Why do you think there's problem with using length of the vector as the “small change in input”? We do want it to tend to zero, after all.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang so g is a function of h, and if I want to find it's derivative I want to find out how g(h) changes related to small changes in h, right? so basically it's derivative has to be limit of delta(h) approaching zero of g(h + delta(h)) - g(h) / delta(h), so why does h equal to delta(h)?

Comment: We only want $g'(0)$, not $g'(h)$ for all $h$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang yeah, but even in case of g'(0) = g(0 + delta(h))  - g(0) / delta(h), why can I replace g(delta(h)) with g(h)?

Comment: In your limits, why have you written $\Delta h\to 0$ instead of $h\to 0$? It should be just $h\to 0$.

Comment: @smcc since by definition of the derivative we have limit of changes approaching zero, not variable itself

Comment: But $h$ *is* the "change". I think you are confused here because often the derivative of a function $g$ of one variable at $x$ is defined as $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{g(x+\Delta x)-g(x)}{\Delta x}$. If we let $h=\Delta x$ then this is the same as $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$.

Comment: @smcc no, h is the independent variable, and delta(h) is the change

Comment: @smcc oh you mean in original post. Sorry, you are right, didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h$ is the free variable of $g(\cdot)$ and of $f\left(x_0+a\times(\cdot), y_0+a\times(\cdot)\right)$.

Let's for argument's sake define these functions independently of each other and we'll give them different free-variable names, viz. $g(h_1)$, $f\left(x+a\times(h_2), y+a\times(h_2)\right)$, $e(x,h_3)\triangleq g(x+h_3)$. Then by the constraint $g(h)=f(x_0+ha,y_0+ha)\,\forall h$ we have $h_1=h_2$.

Now by our definition, $e(x,h_3)=g(x+h_3)=f(x_0+ax+ah_3, y_0+ax+ah_3)$ where $h_1=h_2=x+h_3$ and

$$\begin{align}g'(x)&=\underset{h_3\to 0}{\lim}\frac{e(x,h_3)-g(x)}{h_3}\\
g'(0)&=\underset{h_3\to 0}{\lim}\frac{e(0,h_3)-g(0)}{h_3} \quad \text{$x+h_3=0\implies x=-h_3,\quad $so}\\
g'(0)&=\underset{h_3\to 0}{\lim}\frac{e(0,h_3)-e(0,0)}{h_3}\\
&=\underset{h_3\to 0}{\lim}\frac{f(x_0+a\cdot 0+ah_3, y_0+a\cdot 0+ah_3)-f(x_0+a\cdot 0+a\cdot 0, y_0+a\cdot 0+a\cdot 0)}{h_3}\\
&=\underset{h_3\to 0}{\lim}\frac{f(x_0+ah_3, y_0+ah_3)-f(x_0, y_0)}{h_3}
\end{align}$$

In your post, all $\Delta h$ should be replaced with $h$